# difference between $[a-b] and $((a-b)) in bash

Tags: bash, shell, math, operator-keyword, arithmetic-expressions

I don’t know this operator $[] and couldn’t find something about it. However I know that next two codes give the same output

```
a=4
b=1
echo $[a-b] # => 3
```

and

```
a=4
b=1
echo $((a-b)) # => 3
```

So what is $[] operator for, and what’s the difference with $(()) ?

In my zsh shell prompt, when I open any of them and no close them, I have *mathsubst* written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading `man bash` says that the old format `$[expression]` is deprecated and will be removed. Otherwise they should be equivalent.

> Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression
>   and the substitution of the  result.   The  format for arithmetic
>   expansion is:
>
> ```
>           $((expression))
> ```
>
> The old format `$[expression]` is deprecated and will be removed in
>   upcoming versions of bash.

Comment: Even the deprecation warning was removed from the man page a while ago, although the syntax is still supported as of `bash` 4.4.